# Narrowing a Generic type, compiler is unhappy

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-narrowing

Given this somewhat tortured set-up:

```
enum Mammal {
    Monkey= 'monkey',
    Mouse = 'mouse',
    Cat = 'cat'
}
enum Reptile {
    Lizard='lizard',
    Snake='snake'
}

type ReptileFood = {
    [Reptile.Lizard]: {foodType:'bugs'}
    [Reptile.Snake]: {foodType:'mice'}
}
type MammalFood = {
    [Mammal.Monkey]: {foodType:'bananas'} 
    [Mammal.Mouse]:  {foodType:'cheese'}
    [Mammal.Cat]:  {foodType:'fish'}
}
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

type Animal = keyof MammalFood | keyof ReptileFood
type AnimalFood = ReptileFood & MammalFood

function feedAnimal(animal:Animal, food:ValueOf<AnimalFood>):void{
    console.log(`The ${animal} has eaten the ${food.foodType}`)
}
```

...I would like to create a special case of `feedAnimal` for mammals only:

```
function feedMammal<FoodType extends MammalFood>(animal:keyof MammalFood, food:ValueOf<FoodType>){
    feedAnimal(animal, food)
}
```

But the compiler isn't happy with the type of `food` in the call to `feedAnimal`:

```
 Argument of type 'ValueOf<FoodType>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValueOf<AnimalFood>'.
  Type 'FoodType[string] | FoodType[number] | FoodType[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'ValueOf<AnimalFood>'.
    Type 'FoodType[string]' is not assignable to type 'ValueOf<AnimalFood>'.
      Type 'FoodType[string]' is not assignable to type '{ foodType: "fish"; }'.
        Type 'ValueOf<FoodType>' is not assignable to type '{ foodType: "fish"; }'.
          Type 'FoodType[string] | FoodType[number] | FoodType[symbol]' is not assignable to type '{ foodType: "fish"; }'.
            Type 'FoodType[string]' is not assignable to type '{ foodType: "fish"; }'.
```

How can I make it understand that everything will be fine?

[Playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-SuWitZSZjk2c2iob0ya4YiUVWymjDba3aWwGr2+g2zre0U8-4VVOrRr6alfowdr0gSCwQ08yvpzqK92Yq2Nxt6Iadw9+odjrHD0A)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want

```js
function feedMammal<M extends Mammal>(animal: M, food: MammalFood[M]) {
    feedAnimal(animal, food);
}
```